# Version discrepancy between driver and executor with UDF functions in Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a CSV file which I am reading into a Pyspark dataframe, and then cleaning up; dropping records above a certain length, filtering out depending on contents etc. These all work fine. I am then using a UDF to remove the first character and backfill with zeroes to make the length of the data in the column consistent.

When I ran my code a week ago, it worked fine. It produced expected results, wrote out fine. When I try to run it today, I get a mass of red text in my CDSW console, fundamentally saying that my worker is running Python 2.7, and my driver 3.6. It is only the UDFs that are breaking, and I've tried a few simpler UDFs to see if they work - they don't.

I can't copy the full stacktrace, as its within a virtual environment, but here are two of the main lines typed out:

```
File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.232957/lib.spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 123, in main ("%d.%d" % sys.version_info[:2], version))
Exception: Python in worker has different version 2.7 than that in driver 3.6, Pyspark cannot run with different minor versions.'
```

Some sample code below - this worked a week ago, but now crashes.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

def appender(input):
  ic = input[1:] 
  ic += ((5 - len(ic)) * '0') 
  return ic

append_udf = F.udf(appender, StringType())
df = spark.read.csv('/path/file.csv', header = False)
df_short = df.select(['_c0', '_c1'])
df_length_filtered = df_short.where(F.length('_c0') <= 5)
df_5dig = df_length_filtered.withColumn('_c0',append_udf(df_lenght_filtered['_c0']))
```

Just using something like `test_udf = F.udf(lambda x: x+ 'asaf', StringType())` also brings up the same issue.

This is all done with a tightly controlled CDSW environment, I haven't changed any configuration settings over the last week. Everything else seems to work fine in other functions, its just these UDFs that are throwing up issues. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this is obviously not an issue with your code but with the cluster configuration. i'm not sure how cludera manages the cluster configuration, but on amazon EMR you have to set a special configuration option that sets both PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON environment variables with the same version of python... that is if you want to switch from default python interpreter (e.g. use python3 instead of python2.7, which is their default).

Comment: You are absolutely right. The one thing I'd changed - and forgotten about - was that I'd moved from one CDSW project to a new one. The new one had no environmental variables (under Project Settings/Engine/Environmental Varaiables, whereas the old had PYSPARK_PYTHON with a directory to the 3.6 installer. 

Copying it in, makes the UDFS work perfectly welll - thanks for the advice.